# Resurrecting an old style SRM Amateur power meter?

Tags: power

I decided to put my old SRM amateur chainset on my indoor trainer bike, then charged the SRM V unit, but its not working after the charge. I've not used it in 3 years so not surprised, and Im guessing the strain gauge battery is dead too.

My question is - is it worth resurrecting this since the error margin is 5%? Where can this be done in the UK and how much would it cost

Comment: Phone these guys, they're the UK service centre and should be able to give you the answers you need. http://tinyurl.com/SRM-service-centre

Answer (score 0):

Even if the error is 5%, it's still a power meter. I would get it fixed either to use personnaly or to sell it.